# Container refused to connect when accessing through host web browser

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, devops, cicd

I am new to CICD and DevOps so I am just following the basic steps but could not find where am I making the mistake. I have created a container installed apache2 in it and enabled it and it is running in the container and I have mapped the Docker container's port 80 to my host machine port 82 but when I try to access them using the host IP and port 82 it says refused to connect.
My Jenkins is connected to both master and slave. When I run apache2 in slave it is working as I can see the apache website but when I do the same with the slave IP and port 82 it says connection refused.

#Commands I am using--

sudo docker rm -f $(sudo docker ps -a -q)

sudo docker build /home/ubuntu/workspace/Test -t test

sudo docker run -it -p 82:80 -d test

The output that I am getting---

[image]

My docker file

[image]

Containers running

[image]

Comment: A little more information is needed? Is container running? `docker ps -a`. What is 3.87.40.80? is connecting to port 82 allowed on the host? Is there a firewall? can you curl the container from inside the host? `curl 127.0.0.1:82`.

Comment: Basically, I have an Amazon EC2 instance running of both master and slave. The container is pushed to the docker hub and it is running. 3.87.40.80 is my host IP. I am not sure about that and even if it's another port it says the same(connection refused). curl 127.0.0.1:82 ran the command from inside the host but it says connection refused. @jabbson

Comment: run `docker ps -a` on the host, exec into the container and run `curl 127.0.0.1`, show both outputs

Comment: I have updated my post and https://github.com/bishaldas23/DevOps-Practice-1/blob/master/curlfile this is the output of the curl command

Comment: there is no exposed port in the output of running containers, could you try to expose on a higher port, like 12080? as in '-p 12080:80' and run the same `docker ps -a`?

Comment: Wait, why the command in the output is 'bash'?

Comment: b5acb7a69886   bishal231996/apachecontainer   "bash"    2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   0.0.0.0:12080->80/tcp, :::12080->80/tcp   priceless_snyder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239422/discussion-between-vishal-and-jabbson).

Comment: is AWS VPC firewall configured to allow these requests?

Comment: You seem to have include an image of some sort where you say "my docker file"; that PNG file isn't buildable.  Can you replace the image with the actual text of the `Dockerfile`?  If it's built `FROM` some non-standard image, we'll also need the setup in that base image.

Comment: The problem was my container. I changed it and now its working fine